# How to format date with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I'm having trouble formatting this date with moment.js

> 2016-02-23T08:00:00Z

I just want something like `moment.format("MM DD YYYY")`.

Comment: Did you read the doc, moment.js is [very well documented](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a date in Moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516903/how-to-format-a-date-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code output 02 23 2016

```
moment.utc('2016-02-23T08:00:00Z').format('MM DD YYYY')
```